# EE 2.8.1 Solspace freeform 4.1.5 - composer issue

Tags: solspace-freeform

Using this tag "{exp:freeform:composer form_name="form"}", I'm receiving this output

---

{composer:page}{composer:multi_page_start} {composer:rows}
{composer:columns}

---

EE 2.8.1
Freeform Pro 4.1.5

Is anyone having an issue or am i not aware of change in this updated version?
I've looked over the documentation and i'm doing the same as before.

Anyone have any luck?

Comment: It seems to be only affecting my MSM site. The primary site works with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up duplicating the form and it works now.
Strange enough, seems like the original form became corrupted in my db.